# Dart - Error: Expected a declaration, but got '}'

Tags: flutter, dart

I cannot find the mistake in the below code. Dart shows an error message saying "**Error: Expected a declaration but got '}'**. Could someone please assist?

---

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class WorldTime {

  String location; // Location name for the UI
  String? time; // Time in that location
  String flag; // Url to an asset flag icon
  String url; // This is the location url for the API endpoint

  WorldTime({ required this.location, required this.flag, required this.url });

  }

  Future<void> getTime() async {

    var url;
    var response = await get(Uri.https('worldtimeapi.org', 'api/timezone/$url'));
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    // print(data);

    // get properties from data
    String datetime = data['datetime'];
    String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1,3);
    print(datetime);
    print(offset);

    // Create Datetime object
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));

    // Set the time property
    var time = now.toString();

  }

}
```

Comment: which line are you getting this error?

Comment: Solutions (Just Copy and Paste):

Everything is inside WorldTime() class => https://codeshare.io/amldZo

Seperate WorldTime() class and getTime() function => https://codeshare.io/2j39MD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a closing `}` after `WorldTime` constructor declaration, so that the last `}` in the code you given is extra. The solution is to remove the closing `}` after the `WorldTime({ });` constructor declaration, or remove the last `}`.

Comment: Thanks for your posts. They actually solved the error I was getting but then, when I run, I get the following:
I/flutter ( 9100): null
.....[removed extra lines due to space issues]